# how to completely remove all libraries installed using sudo apt-get install <1st_library_name> <2nd_library_name>, etc?

Tags: apt, sudo, uninstall, compiling, root

I installed Anaconda on Ubuntu 16.04 and created a new environment. Then I started following [this](https://medium.com/@amirsina.torfi/opencv-anaconda-installation-in-ubuntu-98e4707ef611) link to install Opencv in new env. I installed each and every library/package using `sudo apt-get install` ( and later realised that they were installed in my base root). Then I messed up with some configurations while compiling opencv with cmake GUI: `ccmake ..`. I mistakenly configured all the **OFF** options to **ON** in this GUI below [image] and couldn't proceed because of errors which I think occurred due to those changes. Now I can't reconfigure them as they were too many to remember. Therefore I am thinking about completely removing all libraries and packages installed so far in my base root so that I can start installing them again appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

You can do `sudo apt remove package1 package2 package3...`

Then do `sudo apt autoremove` to remove dependencies that you no longer need.

To see which packages you have installed recently, look in `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

Comment: there are too many I am afraid, can I just use `sudo apt autoremove`?

Comment: `sudo apt autoremove` will not remove packages that you have installed with `sudo apt install`, only those that were installed because other packages depended on them at the time.